# Javaからmysqlコマンドを実行し、結果をファイルに書き出したい。

Tags: java, mysql, macos

Javaからmysqlコマンドを実行し、結果をファイルに書き出したいのですがうまく行きません。

実行環境はMacOS 10.11.2です。

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] cmd = new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "mysql", "-u", "root", "-ppassword", "databaseName"};

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
        builder.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.from(new File("sample.sql")));
        builder.redirectOutput(new File("result.tsv"));

        try {
            Process p = builder.start();
            p.waitFor();
            System.out.println(builder.redirectInput());
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

sample.sql `select * from sample;`

コンソールにredirect to read from file "sample.sql"と出力され、
result.tsvは空白のまま生成されます。

ターミナルに直接`mysql -u root -ppassword -D sql2xlsx < sample.sql > result.tsv`と入力した場合は、
result.tsvにはselectの結果が入力されます。

Comment: `import java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect;` と、`builder.redirectOutput(new File("result.tsv"));` の直後に `builder.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);` を入れて、子プロセス(mysql コマンド)のエラーメッセージを表示させる様にしてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。入れたところ、-u: mysql: command not foundと出ます。

Comment: "/bin/sh", "-c", "mysql -u root -ppassword databaseName" でいかがでしょうか?

Comment: @masmさん メッセージが`/bin/sh: mysql: command not found`に変化しましたが、result.tsvは空白のままです。
なぜメッセージが変わったのでしょうか？

Comment: `mysql`コマンドを直接実行して成功するターミナル上で、`java Main`コマンドを実行して失敗しているということでしょうか。あるいは別の方法で実行しているのでしょうか。(`cmd`配列指定方法はmasmさんのものが正しいですね)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメント欄より引用

> /bin/sh: mysql: command not found

`mysql`コマンドが見つからない時に表示されるエラーです。

> p.waitfor();の戻り値は127です。

これも `/bin/sh` が `-c` で指定されたコマンドを見つけられない時に返すコードです。
ターミナル上で次の実行すると再現すると思います。

```
$ /bin/sh -c mysql -u root -p...
/bin/sh: mysql: command not found

$ echo $?
127
```

回避するには `mysql` コマンドをフルパスで指定してみてください。

```
$ /usr/local/bin/mysql -u root -p ...
```

Answer (score 1):

まず正常にmysqlを実行できているかを確認するため、`p.waitFor();`の戻り値(int)を取得してください。
例えばSystem.out.println()を使って出力し、0 でなければ異常終了でしょう。

なお、cmdの配列にて指定しているパスや引数が間違っている場合は、1が戻り値になります。

正しい指定の一例ですが、Windowsであれば

```
String[] cmd = new String[] { "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\bin\\mysql", "-u", "root", "-ppassword", "test" };
```

のようになります。この例では環境変数は使わずに指定していますので、/bin/sh -cで使わずに実行できるかどうかをお試しください。

例えば`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -ppassword test`で実行できるなら、

```
String[] cmd = new String[] { "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql", "-u", "root", "-ppassword", "test" };
```

で実行できるかと思われます（恐れながら、MacOSでの検証はしておりません）

Comment: `p.waitfor();`の戻り値は127です。
また今回の問題は、なぜMacOSにおいてターミナルで実行可能なコマンドがJavaから実行できないのか？です。

ご回答の通り、Windowsではコマンドプロンプトと同じ書き方で実行可能のようです。

Answer (score 1):

PATH 変数の設定が分からないので、解決よりはトラブルシューティングの方法ですが、

ターミナルで

```
$ echo $PATH
```

の出力と、Java プログラムで

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{ "/bin/sh", "-c", "echo $PATH" };
```

を実行した出力を比べてみましょう。`mysql` がインストールされているディレクトリに関して違いがあるはずです。

今、bash の man ページを読み直してみましたが、この問題は ~/.profile の中で PATH をきちんと設定することで解決するでしょう。